# How can I qualify a variable as const/final in Perl?

Tags: perl, constants

For example, in situations like below, I do not want to change the value of `$infilename` anywhere in the program after initialization.

```
my $infilename = "input_56_12.txt";
open my $fpin, '<', $infilename
    or die $!;

...
print "$infilename has $result matches\n";

close $fpin;
```

What is the correct way to make sure that any change in `$infilename` results in not just warnings, but errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use Readonly;
Readonly my $infilename => "input_56_12.txt";
```

Or using the newer [Const::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Const%3a%3aFast) module:

```
use Const::Fast;
const my $infilename => "input_56_12.txt";
```

Comment: Make sure you have Readonly::XS installed as well, for greater speed.

Comment: @daxim: Added it to the answer.

Comment: One other thing -- don't use readonly variables (with the Readonly module *or* Const::Fast) before perl5.10.1 -- there were some interesting bugs.

Answer (score 8):

```
use constant INPUT_FILE => "input_56_12.txt";
```

Might be what you want. If you need to initialize it to something that may change at run time then you might be out of luck, I don't know if Perl supports that.

EDIT: Oh, look at eugene y's answer, Perl does support that.

Comment: how did you figure out from eugene's answer that Perl allows initializing to something that might change at runtime?

Comment: @Lazer => `use` has an implicit `BEGIN` block around it making it a compile time assignment.  the examples in both of eugene's answers work at runtime.  to write the above at runtime `*INPUT_FILE = sub () {"input..."};  print INPUT_FILE();` which is a bit awkward and does not give you any inlining.

Comment: @Lazer: His answer involved using normal variables, but using a special "Readonly" modifier (from a module) to make it illegal to change once it has been defined.

Answer (score 4):

Another popular way to create read-only scalars is to modify the symbol table entry for the variable by using a typeglob:

```
*infilename = \"input_56_12.txt";
```

This only works for global variables ("my" variables have no symbol table entry).

Comment: @eugene: What is a *star* variable?

Comment: That abuses an optimisation for constant subroutines added in perl 5.10.0. `sub foo () { "constant" }` will be stored as a reference to `"constant"` in the symbol table to not require a full glob for just a single value. To be portable, you'd have to do `*foo = sub () { "constant" }`, which also happens to be what the `constant` pragma does, so you might as well use that, get the optimisation, /and/ be portable.

Comment: in my opinion, this is one of the nicest ways to make a constant in Perl, faster than `Readonly`, and without the interpolation and autoquoting issues of constant subs

Comment: @rafl => here the variable is in `$infilename` not `&infilename`, and seems to work fine in 5.8.8

Comment: Ooh, I accidentially read that as a symtab assignment, not a plain glob assignment. `$::{foo} = \42` is what I meant. Sorry!