# How does double arrow (=>) operator work in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, operators, perl-data-structures

I know about the hash use of the `=>` operator, [like this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_hashes.htm)

```
$ cat array.pl
%ages = ('Martin' => 28,
         'Sharon' => 35,
         'Rikke' => 29,);

print "Rikke is $ages{Rikke} years old\n";
$ perl array.pl
Rikke is 29 years old
$
```

and I thought it was just syntax to initialize hashes, but in answers to [How can I qualify a variable as const/final in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090424/how-can-i-qualify-a-variable-as-const-final-in-perl), `=>` has been used like this

```
use Readonly;
Readonly my $infilename => "input_56_12.txt";
```

What exactly does `=>` mean? Are there more ways in which `=>` can be used?

Comment: Fair enough. In my defense, I did Google, which rejected searching for `=>`.

Comment: And a few years later we have [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=perl+%3D%3E) for such searches. Oddly enough, one of the top results is ... this question :)

Comment: I've just been forced into reading Perl scripts for the first time and this question came up. It's been helpful.

Comment: This is really esoteric stuff. Wish there was a book about cool stuff like this. Who knows, maybe there is one already.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `=>` operator in perl is basically the same as comma.  The only difference is that if there's an unquoted word on the left, it's treated like a quoted word.  So you could have written `Martin => 28` which would be the same as `'Martin', 28`.

You can make a hash from any even-length list, which is all you're doing in your example.

Your Readonly example is taking advantage of Perl's flexibility with subroutine arguments by omitting the parenthesis.  It is equivalent to `Readonly(my $infilename, "input_56_12.txt")`.  Readonly is a function exported by the Readonly module which takes two arguments:  a reference, and a value.  The internals of Readonly are worthy of another question if you want to understand them.

Here's an example of using it as a comma in an unexpected way:

```
$ perl -e 'print hello => "world\n"'
helloworld
```

Comment: So, what does `Readonly my $infilename => "input_56_12.txt";` do?

Comment: It is just a comma. You could rewrite it as : `Readonly(my $infilename, "input_56_12.txt");`. For further details on the Readonly module (an alternative to constant), please refer to http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly

Answer (score 40):

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> The `=>` operator is a synonym for the
>   comma except that **it causes its left
>   operand to be interpreted as a string
>   if it begins with a letter or
>   underscore and is composed only of
>   letters, digits and underscores**.
>
> This includes operands that might
>   otherwise be interpreted as operators,
>   constants, single number v-strings or
>   function calls. If in doubt about this
>   behaviour, the left operand can be
>   quoted explicitly.
>
> Otherwise, the => operator behaves
>   exactly as the comma operator or list
>   argument separator, according to
>   context.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> use constant FOO => "something";
> my %h = ( FOO => 23 );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> my %h = ("FOO", 23);
> ```
>
> It is NOT:
>
> ```
> my %h = ("something", 23);
> ```
>
> The `=>` operator is **helpful in
>   documenting the correspondence between
>   keys and values in hashes, and other
>   paired elements in lists**.
>
> ```
> %hash = ( $key => $value );
> login( $username => $password );
> ```

---

From **PBP**:

I have found some good information from **Perl Best Practices** about **Fat Commas** `=>` and i think it should be nice to mention over here too.

It's better to reserve the fat comma exclusively for the following things:-

Use it when **constructing a hash**:

```
my %h = ( FOO => 23 );
```

or when passing **named arguments to a subroutine** ie.,

```
$text = format_text({FOO => 23, BAR => 30});
```

or when **creating a constant**:

```
 Readonly my $FOO => "23";
```

For more detail see the Chapter4:Values and Expressions (Fat Commas) section of Perl Best Practices.