# Is the "=>" operator similar to comma in array context?

Tags: perl

If I use `=>` in an array structure like `my $arr = [ a => b ];`, is it the same thing as `my $arr = [a, b];`? (Actually I have an unrelated question here, why initializing array this way doesn't require `arr` prefixed with `@`? )

Source: http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-operators.html

If this is true, then is there a good reason for perl to have this seemingly obscure feature?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093895/how-does-double-arrow-operator-work-in-perl#4093914

Comment: your unrelated question: you're not initalizing an array, `[ ]` creates a *reference* to an anonymous array. `( )` creates an array

Comment: @BRPocock () creates a list not an array.  There is no way to directly create an array or hash from values.  Only lists and references to arrays and hashes.

Answer (score 7):

The `=>` operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.

**Why?**

The `=>` operator is helpful in documenting the correspondence between keys and values in hashes, and other paired elements in lists. ([source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator))

Answer (score 6):

`a => b` is the same as `'a', b`. Aside from its autoquoting properties, it's useful to imply a relationship. Compare:

```
Point->new('x', $x, 'y', $y)

Point->new(x => $x, y => $y)
```

---

`[ ... ]` creates an (anonymous) array and returns a reference to it.

```
 [ ... ]
```

is similar to

```
 do { my @a = ( ... ); \@a }
```

That's why the result is being assigned to a scalar. If you wanted to create an array, you'd use `my @a`, not `[ ]`.