# Hash argument to constructor in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

```
use PDF::Extract;
$pdf=new PDF::Extract( PDFDoc=>"test.pdf");
$i=1;
$i++ while ( $pdf->savePDFExtract( PDFPages=>$i ) );
```

I am trying to understand the above Perl code.  It appears to be instantiating an object from a module.  What is the argument in the line that calls the constructor?  What does the `=>` mean?  Is it a hash argument?

Comment: Here is a pretty good explanation of what the fat comma can be used for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093895/how-does-double-arrow-operator-work-in-perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor is called via indirect object syntax, which is discouraged (and usually a sign of old code). It would be better written as:

```
my $pdf = PDF::Extract->new(...);
```

The [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax) documentation recommends you avoid indirect object syntax for the following reasons:

> First, it can be confusing to read. In the above example, it's not
>   clear if `save` is a method provided by the `File` class or simply a
>   subroutine that expects a file object as its first argument.
>
> When used with class methods, the problem is even worse. Because Perl
>   allows subroutine names to be written as barewords, Perl has to guess
>   whether the bareword after the method is a class name or subroutine
>   name. In other words, Perl can resolve the syntax as either
>   `File->new( $path, $data )` or `new( File( $path, $data ) )`.

To answer your second question, the `=>` is known as the fat comma, and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) has this to say about it:

> The `=>` operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for
>   the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted
>   as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed
>   only of letters, digits and underscores. This includes operands that
>   might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number
>   v-strings or function calls. If in doubt about this behavior, the left
>   operand can be quoted explicitly.
>
> Otherwise, the `=>` operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or
>   list argument separator, according to context.

In your example code, the constructor receives a list, just like if you had used a normal comma. In fact, your code is equivalent to this:

```
my $pdf = PDF::Extract->new('PDFDoc', 'test.pdf');
```

However, the thing that creates the hash is the assignment on the other side, which may look something like this:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;
    # ...
}
```

The fat comma isn't used exclusively with hashes (nor is it required to initialize a hash, as I pointed out above), but you will typically see it anywhere there's a key/value association in a list of arguments. The shape of the characters makes it clear that "this is related to that". It also saves some typing of quote characters, which is a nice side benefit.

Comment: Ok, so it has nothing to do with hashes?

Comment: @CJ7 Which part? If you're talking about `=>`, you typically see it between key/value pairs in hash assignments, yes.

Comment: Re "Ok, so it has nothing to do with hashes?", Correct. While often used when assigning to a hash, `=>` can be used anywhere `,` is used.

Comment: @ikegami Added clarification paragraph at end.

Comment: @CJ7 Did the clarification answer your question?