# How to understand such this kind of variable to combine _ and other charcters in Perl?

Tags: perl

How to understand such this kind of value in Perl?

```
my %opt = ( _argv => join（" ",@ARGV),_cwd = cwd()).
```

Are `_argv` and `_cwd` both strings?

Comment: Is `_cwd = cwd()` a typo of `_cwd => cwd()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does double arrow (=>) operator work in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093895/how-does-double-arrow-operator-work-in-perl)

Answer (score 7):

[From the reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> The `=>` operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores. This includes operands that might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls. If in doubt about this behavior, the left operand can be quoted explicitly.

```
my %hash = ('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd');
```

can be written as

```
my %hash = (a => 'b', c => 'd');
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone, Now I think _argv and _cwd both are just a variable name, equals to "_argv" and "_cwd".