# beginner problems with mojolicious about "=>"

Tags: mojolicious

In the mojolite script for [MojoExample](https://github.com/tempire/MojoExample/blob/master/mojolite), there are the lines below, I want to know what does "=>" mean in "blogstagtags => tags => 'perlsonal'". I think "=>" is delimiter between hash key and value. Can I find the explanation anywhere?

```
get '/blogs' => sub {
    shift->redirect_to(blogstagtags => tags => 'personal'); # Where is blogstagtags defined? #yaohe
    # blogstagtags is the route name for 'blogs/tag/(*tags)' by default #yaohe
};

get '/blogs/tag/(*tags)' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    # Specified tags to search for: /tag/one/tag/two/tag/three
    my @tags = grep $_ ne 'tag' => split '/' => $self->param('tags');

    my @blogs = $self->db->resultset('Blog')->by_tags(@tags) or return $self->redirect_to('blogs');

    $self->render('blogs/index', blogs => [@blogs],);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blogstagtags => tags => 'personal'
```

is the same as

```
blogstagtags => (tags=>'personal')
```

Now I can answer this question myself. This is a Perl syntax question, not of mojolicious. The hash (tags=>'personal') is passed to the argument 'blogstagtags'.

Answer (score 0):

that operator is only "syntactical sugar"
basically works as the comma `,` expect for extra allowance of the use of "bare word" on the left

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4093914/1681985